# Declaring UIViewController variable property on another ViewController with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am a newbie to Swift. I have started a new project with Swift. I am trying to add SecondViewcontroller view as a subview to the FirstViewController. What i am looking is to declare the SecondViewController property for the FirstViewController. Can anyone please suggest the Swift version of the below code

**FirstViewController.h**

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *listContainerView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondViewController *secondVC;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    self.secondVC  = (SecondViewController *)[mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

    if (![self.secondVC.view isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {
        [self addChildViewController:self.secondVC];
        self.secondVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, listContainerView.frame.size.width, listContainerView.frame.size.height);
        [listContainerView addSubview:self.secondVC.view];
        [self.secondVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
     }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to make a subview, instead of making a new `UIViewController`. In only very special cases would you ever put one `UIViewController` inside another. Basically every 'screen' should have one `UIViewController`, but you shouldn't put one inside another.

Comment: Not necessary, there a lot of architectures that use childViewControllers (just to remain in the Apple framework, the Navigation controller do the same). 
I think that he is asking only for a conversion from his objective-c code to the swift version.

Comment: @MarcoPace but as a beginner, nesting view controllers is rarely ever used and that what he's trying to accomplish is probably to segue to another view. Not trying to assume, but helping on bad app models that encapsulate views on top of one another through child VCs isn't necessarily good for OP.

Comment: Oh, looking from that point of view probably you were right :)

Comment: Another instance where (although a subclass) you would use one viewController in another is dealing with pageViewControllers, tableViewControllers etc... But yeah, I kinda do agree with you on the "make a subview" standpoint

Comment: @MarcoPace All i want to know is creating a property variable of SecondViewController on FirstViewController with Swift.

Comment: `var SecondViewController = SecondViewController()`?